# Loading an Image from documents directory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I cant get my Image(.png) to display.

I check that it exists at the path I use, and it does. But no image appears.

Here is what I've been trying:

```
NSArray  *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir  = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *outputPath    = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[fileList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];



NSString *imgPath = [[outputPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"mov" withString:@"png"]retain];


if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:imgPath]) 
{
    NSLog(@"FOUND IMG");
    NSLog(imgPath);
}


NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgPath]];
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 120)];
[imgView setImage:thumbNail];

[cell addSubview:imgView];
[imgView release];
```

The debug output that confirms the file exists

```
FOUND IMG
2011-12-26 12:42:23.066 iGeo2[412:707] /var/mobile/Applications/1A2B0D85-CDB1-4E4B- 
9509-EF68B1A0E720/Documents/0.009000.png
```

I'm a little baffled. Anybody see where I've made the mistake?

Many Thanks,
-Code

I've tried a few other methods, but nothing ever appears.

Comment: You may get your answer here: 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663511/iphone-how-to-display-document-directory-images-in-image-view

Comment: To use `NSFileManager` simple use the convince method: `NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]` In general check the documentation for class based convince methods. Alss use ARC if possible, it really aces developing code much simpler.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath]` instead of `[NSURL URLWithString:imgPath]`. Image path is not a valid url, it needs a `file://` prefix.

Answer (score 23):

Try to use

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

or

```
NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath]];
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```

Comment: How can i display GIF Image from Document Directory?

Answer (score 4):

You need to give proper file url which will be

```
NSURL *imgURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:imgPath];
```

then initialize your image with proper imgURL var and finally to add the image to your cell you need to do the following

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];
```

I hope it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Filename"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4**

Code:

```
extension FileManager {
    class func getImage(named: String) -> UIImage? {
        let imagePath = getImagePath(named: named)
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
    }

    class func getImagePath(named: String) -> String {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let documentDir = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        return documentDir.appendingPathComponent(named).path
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let image = FileManager.getImage(named: "image.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is perfect.

You need to initialise image with following line

```
UIImage *thumbNail=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

now do this

```
[imgView setImage:thumbNail];

[cell addSubview:imgView];
```