# IOS Show image in textView inside tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I got 2 images from document folder.

I used this code to get 2 images from document folder:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];      
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *directoryContents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myPath error:nil];
NSMutableArray *subpredicates = [NSMutableArray array];
[subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.png'"]];
[subpredicates addObject:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF ENDSWITH '.jpg'"]];
NSPredicate *filter = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:subpredicates];

NSArray *onlyImages = [directoryContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

I got 2 images in array: onlyImages.

I used this code to set images in UIImageView inside TableViewCell.

```
for (int i = 0; i < onlyImages.count; i++) {
    NSString *imagePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[onlyImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
    [self.imgViewInTextView setImage:tempImage];
}
```

But, is only show 1 image in last cell.

Here is image demo.
[image]

Comment: you want to show all images in a cell? or tableview rows count = onlyImages.count?

Comment: No! Inside my tableViewCell have UITextView. 
I want show image inside this TextView.
I'm doing function send image, understand me?.

Comment: what is self.imgViewInTextView? can you show what you do in  tableViewCell

Comment: self.imgViewInTextView is UIImageView. I created this UIImageView to show image.
After that, I used this code to add it in my cell.
[cell.textView addSubview:self.imgViewInTextView];

Comment: I have attach image demo. I have 2 images in array, but it only show 1 image in self.imgViewInTextView inside last cell.

Comment: Make sure that UIImageView contain single image at a time.

Comment: UIImageView can contain only one image

Comment: yes, it contain single image at a time

Comment: Yes! I want image set in UIImageView and inside tableViewCell,

Comment: then u need to add imageView programmatically in cell

Comment: It is same with send image function of facebook.

Comment: I want get images from document folder and show textView inside tableView to do send image function. Understand me?

Comment: My problem is I have 1 array, inside this array have 2 images I got from document folder.

Comment: each cell contain single image, means two image = two cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81240/discussion-between-yagnesh-dobariya-and-vo-mai-trinh).