# How to display images on a table view that are saved in the document directory

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage, save

i'm currently using the UIImagePickerController to allow the user to take a picture which then scales it to 600x800 JPEG and saves it as 4 different qualities (25%, 50%, 75% and 100%). Im trying to find a way in which i can take these images from the documents directory and display them within a table view as thumbnails, which the user can then click on the thumbnail to enlarge the image.

Any help or information would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663511/iphone-how-to-display-document-directory-images-in-image-view

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    NSString *path=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image"];
    UIImageView *imgView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,40,40)];
    imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]];
    [self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Comment: where would i call this method? would it be within the cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Sorry, i'm new to iOS and i am not 100% sure.

Comment: ahh OK, and i need to create a property for the addSubView in my .h file?

Comment: @Fernando- if you are adding on tableview then use [cell.contentview addsubview:imgView];

Comment: As I'm getting: no visible @interface for UIView declares the selector 'addSubView' error

Comment: [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

Comment: OK, thanks very much for the help Vivek Sehrawat, got it to build, im just having an error with my table view which ill solve myself hopefully.