# iOS - save image in jpg format

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

My question is what format the image is saved, if is dat or jpg. This is the code that i used:

```
    NSString * urlImage = .....;
    NSString * _folderPath = .....;

    NSString * imageName = [[urlImage componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
        NSString * jpegPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_folderPath,imageName];

        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:jpegPath])
        {
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlImage];
            //Download image
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

            //Save image
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
            [data writeToFile:jpegPath atomically:YES];
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following is piece of code for save **.jpg** image

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path =  [docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image1.jpg"];

NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 80)];
NSError *writeError = nil;
[imageData writeToFile:path options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. One question, the file is saved in .dat or .jpg? and is necessary to retrieve with a NSData?

Comment: @RodDL - for get image from document directory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663511/iphone-how-to-display-document-directory-images-in-image-view

Comment: how can I change resolution of photo while saving yo JPG?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

`stringByAppendingPathComponent` method to create or get exact valid path

Use this way:

```
    NSString * jpegPath = [_folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];// [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",_folderPath,imageName];
```

Comment: Thanks i modified the line!