# Store image in .jpg Format

Tags: ios, xcode5.1, ios-camera

capture image from camera in app.
and I want save it .jpg format.
but I don't know how to save in .jpg?

I found two methods UIImagePNGRepresentation,  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(TempImage, 0.5);

but I want to save in jpg format.

Comment: check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677644/ios-save-image-in-jpg-format)

Comment: and what do you think about the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation(...)` generates which format? I would not like to spoil the surprise when you get it, but hopefully the extra letter E won't confuse you too much...