# How to load png image from document in UIWebView in iOS 8 Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiwebview

I have some png image in my document and i wanna to load these images in UIWebView like

```
<img src='/Users/rezakhalafi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1784E9F2-4DCA-4D72-A7B0-1D74AFAFDFBA/data/Containers/Data/Application/54A0319C-A33D-4993-9CA3-20F73B8CD85F/Documents/CACHE/cache332377/9cache.png'>
```

But it does not work.
I am using Objective C.
Please help me.

Comment: see this once it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663511/iphone-how-to-display-document-directory-images-in-image-view

Comment: No, i wanna set document image address in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
just add file:/ at the begin of address string.

```
<img src='file:/Users/rezakhalafi/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1784E9F2-4DCA-4D72-A7B0-1D74AFAFDFBA/data/Containers/Data/Application/54A0319C-A33D-4993-9CA3-20F73B8CD85F/Documents/CACHE/cache332377/9cache.png'>
```