# How can i show Images from Sqlite to a uicollectionview

Tags: swift, xcode, sqlite, uicollectionview, uiimage

I have some images in sqlite database. I saved Image in BLOB type (I converted in img.pngdata as NSData and save it to db). Now I want to retrieve images and show them in a uicollectionview view. when I retrieve image it is like [this
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6awt.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6awt.png). Which type of array should I use to show them in collection view? The table in the db is [like this[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp6OQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp6OQ.png).

Also, how can I get the image name as a string from the retrieved image?

Comment: I think you need to save Image in SQLite in the form of BASE64 String. And when you need to retrieve image, just Decode it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing and Retrieving Image in Sqlite with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780937/storing-and-retrieving-image-in-sqlite-with-swift)

Comment: can you tell me sqlite bind statement for if i save base64steing

Comment: It will be the same as you are doing for simple String based Text...

Comment: currently i am sqlite3_bind_blob which is not accepting base64str i try to bind with text it also gives error

Comment: I think it should work with TEXT or BLOG... What Error you are getting?

Comment: The second option is to save Image in DB is ... store Image in App Doc Directory with a unique name ... and then store this Unique Name in your SQLite DB... And when you will retrieve any Image, just get the Image name from the DB and then find the image from your Document directory with the Image Name... I think its the BEST and SIMPLE solution. Thanks

Comment: well , this could be easy for me let me try this ..Thank you very much

Comment: Sounds great... Welcome.

Comment: Please refrain from keeping meta-commentary into the question, it is not productive and compromises the question's readability. Moreover, as per the [asking guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), requesting a recommendation for off-site resources, such as tutorials, is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by retrieving the blob data like this:

```
let lenght:Int = Int(sqlite3_column_bytes(queryStatement, 0));
let imgdata : NSData = NSData(bytes: sqlite3_column_blob(queryStatement, 0), length: lenght)
let decoded_img : UIImage = UIImage(data: imgdata as Data)!
imageNames.append(decoded_img)
```

I declared an array of type `UIImage`, then used it in `uicollectionview` view, it is now working fine for me.